# Read Data from table with no relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have some global information (Company name, street, phone, …) stored in a table "CompInfo".
This table has only one entry and has no relationship to other tables.

Now I need this information in a view to generate, i.e. offers.
I tried to add this data in the controller, but I don't know how I can send this info to my view.

Here is my controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Offer(int qry_offer)
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Offer";


    var x412Context = _context.Offer
        .Where(m => m.Id == qry_offer);


    x412Context = x412Context
        .Include(o => o.Kunde)
        .Include(o => o.Mandant)
        .Include(m => m.OfferPos)
            .ThenInclude(m => m.Ust)
        ;
    return View(await x412Context.ToListAsync());
}
```

First I add the following code

```
var Comp_Info = _context.CompInfo
    .Where(m => m.Id == 1);
```

With breakpoints and debugging I see that **Comp_Info** has the information I require.
But I don´t know how to get this info to my view.

I tried

```
ViewData["street"] = Comp_Info.street;
```

But this doesn't work.

Does anyone have an idea how I can transmit the data to the view?

Comment: I'd steer away from using ViewData. You lose the strongly typed goodness of C# if you do that. If you stick to creating a view model that contains all the data, and pass that to your view, everything stays a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a viewmodel in your Offer method that looks like this :

```
public class FooVM
{
  public List<Offer> Offers {get; set;}
  public CompInfo CompInfo{get; set;}
}
```

and in your controller initilize the FooVm like this:

```
var vm = new FooVM 
{
  Offers = await x412Context.ToListAsync(),
  CompInfo =  Comp_Info 
};
```

and then in your Offer Method you return View(vm);

then your Offer.cshtml will look something like :

```
@model FooVm;
// some html code 
@foreach (var offer in Model.Offers)
{
// Do something
}
<span>@Model.CompInfo.Street</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. 
This was helpful.
In my view I had to change the first line to:

`@model racknex.Models412.FooVM` 
instead of 
`@model FooVM`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can add a using in your _ViewImports.cshtml file to the namespace racknex.Models412 like this @ using racknex.Models412;  wihch will allow you to write only @ model FooVM. not much of a difference just looks cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement another class which should have members as the list (of the same type `x412Context.ToListAsync()`) and another member which will have the same datatype as `Comp_Info.street`.

then you can return the same class object to the view like return `View(newClassObj);`, you can access it as we do to access model class members in view.